# Escaping %E1 in ruby

Tags: ruby, decode

I'm parsing some sports data, including names like 'Olaz%E1bal' and '%C1lvaro Morata' from an external feed (read: I can't change it).  I want to decode these strings, but I can't figure out how.  Here's what I've tried:

**URI.unescape**:

```
Expected: "Olazábal"
Actual: "Olaz\xE1bal"
```

**CGI::unescape**:

```
Expected: "Olazábal"
Actual: "Olaz\xE1bal"
```

**CGI::unescape_html**:

```
Expected: "Olazábal"
Actual: "Olaz%E1bal"
```

**HTMLEntities.decode**:

```
Expected: "Olazábal"
Actual: "Olaz%E1bal"
```

Comment: Did you check the string encoding? `\xE1` is the latin1 representation of á, so it would be invalid in a unicode-encoded string. Try to enforce a latin1-encoding by calling `.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')` on the string.

Comment: that's exactly what i ended up doing - `.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')`

Comment: Hm, postet it as answer — dunno why I wrote it as a comment. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the string encoding? `\xE1` is the latin1 representation of `á`, so it would be invalid in a utf-8 encoded string. Try to enforce a latin1 encoding by calling `.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')` on the string.

Also mind that it is common to use UTF-8 in URLs as well, e.g. one would encode `á` as `%C3%A1`.